# Reason behind the get prefix in c#

Tags: .net, reflection, syntax, properties, getter

Considering that in c# we have a specific syntax for properties with getters and setters, why are some properties accessed with methods (usually prefixed with 'Get') instead of a getter?

for example why is it:

```
var properties = object
    .GetType()
    .GetProperties();
```

instead of using a getter like:

```
var properties = object
    .Type
    .Properties
```

Comment: I guess this stems from the historic notion that a method should refer to a verb. I try to avoid this and also use properties rather than methods.

Comment: Didn't see that typo, thanks @xanatos

Comment: @MarkusDeibel I knew why it's `GetType()` instead of `Type()`. What I don't understand is why it's not just `Type`. Hopefully, I rephrased my question to make that more obvious.

Comment: this is a .net question, not a c# one.

Comment: the latter in your example is actually a `property` and not a `method`. Due to MS guidelines "heavy" execution should be performed in methods and not properties - which is probably why they opted for methods rather than props

Comment: This is pure speculation but maybe the `GetType()` method was defined before the C# team knew that they would add Properties to their langauge

Comment: If something behaves like a variable, I implement it as a property. If it behaves more like a function, I create a method. For instance, if I have to do a lot of work to get the data, I generally use a method. Also, if it's implemented as an extension, it has to be a method.

Comment: another speculation would be that they might want to take parameters at some point.

Comment: You can create overloaded methods for `GetType`. By using `properties` or `auto-implemented properties` you can't do it.

Comment: @nover I did a quick search but can't seem to find those guidelines, what's considered 'heavy'?

Comment: @Freggar Incorrect. Properties were right there from the get-go. See https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-334%201st%20edition%20December%202001.pdf page 35.

Comment: @Halex anything that is not simply looking up a value in memory. Also the accepted answer explains it pretty well. It's mentioned in Mirosofts Design Guidelines Book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Design Guidelines for Developing Class Libraries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229054(v=vs.100).aspx)  have this to say:

> Consider using a property if the member represents a logical attribute of the type.

`GetType()` is defined on `object`, the base type for all types. You don't want *each* type to always have a `Type` property.

> Do use a property, rather than a method, if the value of the property is stored in the process memory and the property would just provide access to the value.

Some translation is required to translate the CLR's internal metadata to PropertyInfo objects, as far as I know.

Comment: Yes. If my properties are anything more than a trivial lookup, I consider them to be false advertising.

Comment: @codecaster I think the first guideline ("Consider using a property...") would support more a `Type` property than a `GetType` method. The example given in the text (about a property of `ListView`, `BorderStyle`, in WPF), could be extended by looking at the `Control` class (that is the baseclass of all WPF controls, like `Object` is the baseclass of all .NET objects) that has tons of properties that are shared by all the subclasses of `Control`. Unless you want to make a logical attribute vs meta-attribute (the `Type` is a meta-attribute of the object)

Answer (score 1):

The `GetProperties()` answer is simple: it returns a new array of properties (a filtered (only public) copy of the internal array of properties) for every call, and from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229054(v=vs.100).aspx):

> Do use a method, rather than a property, in the following situations.
>
> The operation returns a copy of an internal state (this does not include copies of value type objects returned on the stack).

and

> The operation returns an array.

For the `GetType()` I don't know.